# Text in richtextbox applying text decorations outside of selection

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

I have a WPF desktop application that uses MVVM architecture. I started making it following Tim Buchalka's "Windows Presentation Foundation Masterclass" on Udemy (paid course, only mentioning it in case anyone already knows what it's about), specifically the part with making a simple Evernote Clone.

I have a `RichTextBox` and several buttons that allow the user to change the formatting of the currently selected text - bold, italics, underline and strikethrough. Bold and italics work perfectly fine, the issue is with underline and strikethrough. I can apply either of the properties fine as long as it's the same in the entire selection (all underlined, all strikethrough, both or neither). But when I try to apply the styling to a selection, where one part is udnerlined/strikethrough and the other is not, the formatting gets applied to a text range that is offset compared to the selection itself (not to mention that the styling isn't applied the way I would have like, but the offset is currently the bigger problem). I'll try adding pictures to better illustrate what I mean.

Styling working correctly when the selection is homogenous:

[image: Styling working correctly when the selection is homogenous]

Selected non-homogenous part of text, about to click the underline button:

[image: Selected non-homogenous part of text, about to click the underline button]

How the styling gets applied after I clicked the button:

[image: How the styling gets applied after I clicked the button]

I tried to figure out what's going on using breakpoints, but the method only seems to iterate through the selection, as intended. I'll appreciate any advice and/or constructive criticism. Anyways, here's my code:

Bold button's method:

```cs
private void btnUnderline_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool isButtonChecked = (sender as ToggleButton).IsChecked ?? false;
    TextDecorationCollection textDecorations = new TextDecorationCollection();
    try
    {
        textDecorations.Add( contentRichTextBox.Selection.GetPropertyValue( 
            Inline.TextDecorationsProperty) as TextDecorationCollection);
        if (isButtonChecked)
        { textDecorations.Add(TextDecorations.Underline); }
        else { textDecorations.TryRemove(TextDecorations.Underline, out textDecorations);}
        contentRichTextBox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, 
            textDecorations);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        textDecorations = new TextDecorationCollection();
        if (!contentRichTextBox.Selection.IsEmpty)
        {
            var tpFirst = contentRichTextBox.Selection.Start;
            var tpLast = contentRichTextBox.Selection.End;
            var textRange = new TextRange(tpFirst, tpFirst.GetPositionAtOffset(1));
            var underlined = (textRange.GetPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty) 
                as TextDecorationCollection).Contains(TextDecorations.Underline[0]);
            for (TextPointer t = tpFirst; 
                 t.CompareTo(tpLast) <= 0; 
                 t = t.GetPositionAtOffset(1))
            {
                textDecorations.Clear();
                textRange = new TextRange(t, t.GetPositionAtOffset(1));
                textDecorations = textRange.GetPropertyValue( 
                    Inline.TextDecorationsProperty) as TextDecorationCollection;
                if (!underlined)
                { textDecorations.Add(TextDecorations.Underline[0]); }
                else { textDecorations.TryRemove(TextDecorations.Underline, 
                       out textDecorations); }
                textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, 
                     textDecorations);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NewParagraphWhenSelectionIsEmpty();
        }
    }
}
```

Strikethrough button's method:

```cs
private void btnStrikethrough_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bool isButtonChecked = (sender as ToggleButton).IsChecked ?? false;
    TextDecorationCollection textDecorations = new TextDecorationCollection();
    try
    {
        textDecorations.Add(contentRichTextBox.Selection.GetPropertyValue( 
            Inline.TextDecorationsProperty) as TextDecorationCollection);
        if (isButtonChecked)
        { textDecorations.Add(TextDecorations.Strikethrough); }
        else { textDecorations.TryRemove(TextDecorations.Strikethrough, 
               out textDecorations); }
        contentRichTextBox.Selection.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, 
             textDecorations);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        textDecorations = new TextDecorationCollection();
        if (!contentRichTextBox.Selection.IsEmpty)
        {
            var tpFirst = contentRichTextBox.Selection.Start;
            var tpLast = contentRichTextBox.Selection.End;
            var textRange = new TextRange(tpFirst, tpFirst.GetPositionAtOffset(1));
            var strikedthrough = (textRange.GetPropertyValue( 
                  Inline.TextDecorationsProperty) as 
                  TextDecorationCollection).Contains(TextDecorations.Strikethrough[0]);
            for (TextPointer t = tpFirst; 
                 t.CompareTo(tpLast) <= 0;
                 t = t.GetPositionAtOffset(1))
            {
                textDecorations.Clear();
                textRange = new TextRange(t, t.GetPositionAtOffset(1));
                textDecorations = textRange.GetPropertyValue( 
                    Inline.TextDecorationsProperty) as TextDecorationCollection;
                if (!strikedthrough)
                { textDecorations.Add(TextDecorations.Strikethrough[0]); }
                else { textDecorations.TryRemove(TextDecorations.Strikethrough,
                       out textDecorations); }
                textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty, 
                    textDecorations);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NewParagraphWhenSelectionIsEmpty();
        }
    }
}
```

Method used when selection in the richtextbox changes:

```cs
private void contentRichTextBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedWeight = contentRichTextBox.Selection.GetPropertyValue( 
        FontWeightProperty);
    btnBold.IsChecked = (selectedWeight != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) 
                         && (selectedWeight.Equals(FontWeights.Bold));

    var selectedStyle = contentRichTextBox.Selection.GetPropertyValue(FontStyleProperty);
    btnItalics.IsChecked = (selectedStyle != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) 
                         && (selectedStyle.Equals(FontStyles.Italic));

    var selectedDecoration = contentRichTextBox.Selection.GetPropertyValue( 
             Inline.TextDecorationsProperty) as TextDecorationCollection;

    btnUnderline.IsChecked = (selectedDecoration != null)
        && (selectedDecoration != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
        && selectedDecoration.Contains(TextDecorations.Underline[0]);

    btnStrikethrough.IsChecked = (selectedDecoration != null)
        && (selectedDecoration != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
        && selectedDecoration.Contains(TextDecorations.Strikethrough[0]);

    cbEditorFontFamily.SelectedItem = contentRichTextBox.Selection.GetPropertyValue( 
                                      Inline.FontFamilyProperty);

    if (contentRichTextBox.Selection.GetPropertyValue(Inline.FontSizeProperty)
        != DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)
    { cbEditorFontSize.Text = (contentRichTextBox.Selection.GetPropertyValue( 
                              Inline.FontSizeProperty)).ToString(); }
}
```

Method used when inserting a new paragraph:

```cs
private void NewParagraphWhenSelectionIsEmpty()
{
    var fontFamily = new FontFamily(cbEditorFontFamily.SelectedItem.ToString());
    var fontSize = Convert.ToDouble(cbEditorFontSize.Text);
    var fontStyle = (btnItalics.IsChecked ?? false) ? FontStyles.Italic : 
                    FontStyles.Normal;
    var fontWeight = (btnItalics.IsChecked ?? false) ? FontWeights.Bold : 
        FontWeights.Normal;

    var textDecorations = new TextDecorationCollection();
    if (btnUnderline.IsChecked ?? false)
    { textDecorations.Add(TextDecorations.Underline[0]); }
    if (btnStrikethrough.IsChecked ?? false)
    { textDecorations.Add(TextDecorations.Strikethrough[0]); }

    // Check to see if we are at the start of the textbox and nothing has been added yet
    if (contentRichTextBox.Selection.Start.Paragraph == null)
    {
        // Add a new paragraph object to the richtextbox with the fontsize
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        p.FontFamily = fontFamily;
        p.FontSize = fontSize;
        p.FontStyle = fontStyle;
        p.FontWeight = fontWeight;
        p.TextDecorations = textDecorations;
        contentRichTextBox.Document.Blocks.Add(p);
    }
    else
    {
        // Get current position of cursor
        TextPointer curCaret = contentRichTextBox.CaretPosition;
        // Get the current block object that the cursor is in
        Block curBlock = contentRichTextBox.Document.Blocks.Where
            (x => x.ContentStart.CompareTo(curCaret) == -1 
            && x.ContentEnd.CompareTo(curCaret) == 1).FirstOrDefault();
        if (curBlock != null)
        {
            Paragraph curParagraph = curBlock as Paragraph;
            // Create a new run object with the fontsize, and add it to the current block
            Run newRun = new Run();
            newRun.FontFamily = fontFamily;
            newRun.FontSize = fontSize;
            newRun.FontStyle = fontStyle;
            newRun.FontWeight = fontWeight;
            newRun.Foreground = new 
                   SolidColorBrush((Color)wpfcpEditorFontColour.SelectedColor);    
            newRun.TextDecorations = textDecorations;
            curParagraph.Inlines.Add(newRun);
            // Reset the cursor into the new block. 
            // If we don't do this, the font size will default again when you start 
            // typing.
            contentRichTextBox.CaretPosition = newRun.ElementStart;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the fragment code above you trying to apply text decoration **inside** a selection. So why the question is titled 'applying text decorations **outside** of selection'? Somehow incomprehensible.

Comment: It might be an imperfect title for my problem, so if it's possible to edit the title, feel free to suggest a better one. The TLDR summary of my problem is, that while I only want to apply the text decorations to the selection, they're getting applied outside the selection as well (which I don't want).

Comment: One question: _Why you are dealing with the Exception? What is a functionality you are putting under `catch (Exception)` block?_

Comment: @Jackdaw The try part of the code takes care of cases where the TextDecorations in the entire selection are homogenous (all with underline or all without underline, all with strikethrough or all without it). The code under `catch (Exception)` is meant to apply text decorations when only part of the selection has underline/strikethrough. I'm trying to do that by iterating through 1 character long text ranges of the selection and applying/removing the TextDecoration in question as needed.

Comment: @Jackdaw  To clarify, the intended behaviour with non-homogenous selection is the same as in MS Word for example - if the first character of the selection is already underlined, the entire selection should lose the underline altogether (but keep strikethrough if any characters have it). And if the first character of the selection doesn't have the TextDecoration in question, it should be applied to the entire selection (again, keeping the other TextDecoration intact if it's present).